# Python merge dictionaries within a while loop

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a function `part_func(x)` that returns a dictionary. I want to run the function in a while loop that is part of another function `main_func()`.

The results of the `part_func(x)` look like this:

```
{'age': 80, 'name': 'peter'}
{'age': 20, 'name': 'stefan'}
```

I would like to get as a return from the `main_func()` a dictionary like this:

```
{'age': [80, 20], 'name': ['peter', 'stefan']}
```

The following code does that job:

```
dicts1 = dict1, dict2
dicts2 = {k:[d.get(k) for d in dicts1] for k in {k for d in dicts1 for k in d}}
```

My question now is, how can I implement this into the `main_func()`?

```
def part_func(x):
    # produces dicitionary

def main_func():
    for x in range(10):
       return part_func(x) # returns dictionary
```

Comment: First, just use `for x in range(10)` and get rid of the `x=0` and `x+=1`. Second, if you're going to `return part_func(x)` each time through the loop, you're only going to go through the loop once anyway, so… what exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather use something like this:

```
def main_func():
    final_d = {}
    for _ in range(10):
        for key, val in part_func().items():
            final_d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
    return final_d
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try this

```
def part_func(x):
    # produces dicitionary

def main_func():
    res = {}
    for x in range(10):
        for k,v in part_func(x).iteritems():
            res.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return  res
```

Comment: what is the difference between `part_func(x).iteritems()` and `part_func().items()`?

Comment: `iteritems()` doesn't create list in memory just iterates over items while `items()` create list (this is in python 2.x)